# View pages are invisible in my solution explorer in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, view

I have view pages that have gone invisible in my solution explorer but I can navigate to the pages when I run my program.

For example I can navigate to [Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kviwk.png)

But when I look in my inventory reports view folder this is all I see

[solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuDMb.png)

Why are the view files invisible?

Comment: I'm looking for my view pages. ItemSerialQty is one of my view pages but as you can see in the solution explorer picture. The view page isn't showing up. I could see it yesterday but I can't see it this morning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it was excluded from your solution. You can manually include by:

1. Click show all files
   [like the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avaOZ.png)
2. Then traverse to your view file, do the right click on it
3. Choose Include in project

Comment: Did you add the file by copying it in your file explorer? That could cause this problem. Or maybe your .csproj file was edited due to conflict from source control?

Comment: I didn't copy a file. But I was working with different branches so maybe that caused an issue